# Problema con la API de Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-v3

Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en la que marco puntos en el mapa en base a la dirección obtenida, como no tengo las coordenadas de la dirección que quiero marcar investigando vi que google tiene el objeto Geocoder que me permite codificar la dirección dada y así obtener las coordenadas para marcarlo en el mapa

```
<script>
    var gCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var objInformacion = {
        address: "Juan Pablos 150 Nte. Primero de Cobián, Torreón, Coahuila"
    }

    gCoder.geocode(objInformacion, fn_coder);

    function fn_coder(datos)
    {
        var coordenadas = datos[0].geometry.location; 

        var config = {
            map: gMapa,
            position: coordenadas,
            title: "Colegio Cervantes",
            icon: "img/icono.png"
        }

        var gMarkerDV = new google.maps.Marker(config);
    }

<script>
```

Se supone con este código hago lo que expuse arriba, el problema aquí es que cuando ejecuto mi aplicación web me marca este error:

Geocoding Service: This API project is not authorized to use this API.

Como puedo solucionar esto??

Comment: ¿Activate las APIs "Geolocating" y "Geocoding" en la [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)?

Comment: Efectivamente el problema aquí era que no tenia activado el Geocoding, lo active y funciono de maravilla, solamente entre a la consola de de google y active el servicio de Geocoding.

Comment: @Guz, por favor publique su comentario para que el OP pueda aceptar su respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que asegurarse de que la API de Geocoding esté habilitada en la consola de Google Cloud, en el mismo proyecto que se configuró para la API de Maps JavaScript.